# Install wine via Homebrew: Problem with zlib

Tags: macos, homebrew, wine

I've got a problem with my installation of wine. (OS 10.8.2, XCode 4.5.2)

With the information I found, I already fixed a few errors, but now I'm stuck on a missing component called 'zlib' and I can't install it via brew. Another error while installing wine appears while `make install` for `libicns`
Anyone got an idea?

Here is my installation-output:

```
brew install libpng --universal
==> Downloading http://downloads.sf.net/project/libpng/libpng15/1.5.13/libpng-1.
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libpng-1.5.13.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13
checking for memset... yes
checking for pow... yes
checking for zlibVersion in -lz... no
checking for z_zlibVersion in -lz... no
configure: error: zlib not installed
```

or

```
brew install libicns
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/icns/libicns-0.8.1.tar.
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libicns-0.8.1.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libicns/0.8.1
==> make install
      _WritePNGImage in icns2png.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [icns2png] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Have you installed all previous brew receipies with --universal?

Comment: Type `brew doctor`. In the end of message will be `Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries
with other strange results.` and list of keg-only formulaes - `brew unlink` all of them and `zlib` too. Edit: it's too old question and my comment is actual for different situation, but it could help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew rm libpng  
brew install libpng --universal  
brew install wine --with-gcc
```

Comment: Why does this solve the problem? `brew install libpng -- univeral` is something which already was tried.